# Using Perl to select 1 from@db_link where db_link comes from each entries of a lookup table

Tags: database, oracle, perl, lookup

I want to read a table in Oracle which contains database links for checking availability of each database link  and return only the bad results for each database link and error message.

I want to fetch this lookup table into an array, and pass the entries of db_link to a select from dualQdb_link, test all the entries of lookup to test for success or failure. This seems very hard to achieve in perl.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Seems pretty straightforward, something like this:

```
# Or whatever the column is really named ;)
my $dblinks = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref("select dbname from db_link");

for my $dblink (@$dblinks) {
  my $success = eval {
    my ($ret) = $dbh->selectrow_array("select 1 from "
      . $dbh->quote_identifier($dblink, undef, "dual") );
    $ret;
  };

  if ($success) {
    say "$dblink is up";
  } else {
    say "$dblink is down";
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `quote_identifier()`.  For pedantry points, I think the dynamic SQL should be:  `"SELECT 1 FROM " . $dbh->quote_identifer('dual', undef, $dblink)`.

Comment: @pilcrow: Actually, you've got that backwards.  It's ` $dbh->quote_identifier( 'link', 'schema', 'table' );` so it would be `"SELECT 1 FROM " . $dbh->quote_identifer($dblink, undef, 'dual')`.